# Editar Dataframe pandas .groupby

Tags: python, pandas, data

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import dataiku
from dataiku import pandasutils as pdu
import pandas as pd
mydataset = dataiku.Dataset("PRD_edited_rejoined")
mydataset_df = mydataset.get_dataframe()`
mydataset_df[u"Válido"] = (mydataset_df.groupby([u"name"])
                      [u"RREF1", u"RREF2", u"RREF3"]
                      .transform("nunique", dropna=False)
                      .sum(axis=1) == 3
                     )

cols_names = [u'name', u'ref', u'RREF1', u'RREF2', u'RREF3', u'Válido']
my_cols_df = mydataset_df[cols_names]
```

El código es para agrupar los `items` por nombre y luego comparar si los RREF1, 2 Y 3 son iguales.

Bien eso esta hecho y me retorna "**FALSE**" cuando no son iguales por grupo de nombres.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---- Ahora lo que hay que hacer es como se ve en la imagen cambiar los valores de los `RREF` por grupo de nombres para que todos sean iguales, en el caso del a imagen seria copiar los valores de la fila 6 a la fila 7.

- Alguna idea de como hacer eso?

Comment: De preferencia que el código sea texto es mas facil para leer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres en definitiva es que todas las columnas RREF para un mismo valor de `name` tengan el mismo valor (en este caso el de la primera fila que se encuentre), una forma muy simple sin tener que crear siquiera la columna de validación es usar `appl`y sobre cada grupo y con `loc` asignar a todas las filas del grupo el valor de la primera en esas columnas.

Vamos a crear primero un ejemplo reproducible:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

csv =StringIO(u'''\
name,ref,RREF1,RREF2,RREF3
arandela carpeta,32,1,7,8
arandela carpeta,33,1,6,3
arandela carpeta,34,5,7,8
az,6166,5,3,10
az,6541,5,3,10
Babero Terry,6089,2,6,1
Babero Terry,8089,1,7,18
''')

df = pd.read_csv(csv)
print(df)
```

Con lo que tenemos el siguiente DataFrame:

> ```
>                name   ref  RREF1  RREF2  RREF3
> 0  arandela carpeta    32      1      7      8
> 1  arandela carpeta    33      1      6      3
> 2  arandela carpeta    34      5      7      8
> 3                az  6166      5      3     10
> 4                az  6541      5      3     10
> 5      Babero Terry  6089      2      6      1
> 6      Babero Terry  8089      1      7     18
> ```

Aplicando la idea anteriormente mencionada:

```
def set_RREFs(g):
    cols = ["RREF1", "RREF2", "RREF3"]
    df.loc[g.index, cols] = g[cols].iloc[0].values

_ = df.groupby('name').apply(set_RREFs)
```

obtenemos (la modificación es **in-place**):

> ```
> >>> df
>                name   ref  RREF1  RREF2  RREF3
> 0  arandela carpeta    32      1      7      8
> 1  arandela carpeta    33      1      7      8
> 2  arandela carpeta    34      1      7      8
> 3                az  6166      5      3     10
> 4                az  6541      5      3     10
> 5      Babero Terry  6089      2      6      1
> 6      Babero Terry  8089      2      6      1
> ```

- `df.loc[g.index, cols]` selecciona las filas que pertenecen al grupo de turno en el DataFrame (las que tiene el mismo valor en `name`) y por cada fila selecciona también las tres columnas RREF.
- `g[cols].iloc[0].values` nos permite obtener los valores de estas tres columnas en la primera fila del grupo.

---

**Edición:**

Si se desea crear un nuevo DataFrame solo hay que hacer que la función retorne el grupo con las modificaciones pertinentes:

```
def set_RREFs(group):
    cols = ["RREF1", "RREF2", "RREF3"]
    group[cols] = group[cols].iloc[0].values
    return group

df2 = df.groupby('name').apply(set_RREFs)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>                name   ref  RREF1  RREF2  RREF3
> 0  arandela carpeta    32      1      7      8
> 1  arandela carpeta    33      1      6      3
> 2  arandela carpeta    34      5      7      8
> 3                az  6166      5      3     10
> 4                az  6541      5      3     10
> 5      Babero Terry  6089      2      6      1
> 6      Babero Terry  8089      1      7     18
>
> >>> df2
>                name   ref  RREF1  RREF2  RREF3
> 0  arandela carpeta    32      1      7      8
> 1  arandela carpeta    33      1      7      8
> 2  arandela carpeta    34      1      7      8
> 3                az  6166      5      3     10
> 4                az  6541      5      3     10
> 5      Babero Terry  6089      2      6      1
> 6      Babero Terry  8089      2      6      1
> ```

Comment: Aplique el la formula recomendada pero el resultado es 0, cero filas, cero columnas **IMAGEN DE REFERENCIA** **(http://nimb.ws/v0yhxE)**

Comment: @Yan Chirino el DataFrame se modifica **in-place**, retorna un dataframe vacío resultado de **apply**, pero **es el propio dataframe original (`df` en mi ejemplo y `mydataset_df` en tu caso,el que se modifica)**.

Comment: @YanChirino si deseas un DataFrame nuevo he editado la respuesta (ver al final) para mostrar como se puede hacer.